# How can the google maps show the places which include specific words (Android studio)?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

i currently work for the google maps to finding specific places.

I tried to use PlaceType but it includes only general words like Restaurant etc.

I want to make a search function which can search the places with specific words or names.

```
public void showPlaceInformation(LatLng location)
{
    mMap.clear();

    if (previous_marker != null)
        previous_marker.clear();

    new NRPlaces.Builder()
            .listener(MainActivity.this)
            .key("Key")
            .latlng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            .radius(500)
            .type(PlaceType.RESTAURANT)
            .build()
            .execute();
}
```

The code works very fine but the PlaceType is very limited. So i want to change the code to find specific place.

Comment: have you try using setKeyword("Restaurant"), and change setting type to null .type(null)?

Comment: Can you please explain more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

```
new NRPlaces.Builder()
            .listener(MainActivity.this)
            .key("Key")
            .latlng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
            .radius(500)
            .keyword("Restaurant")
            .type(null)
            .build()
            .execute();
```